# List or Array of Years between two given dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 Dates in MMM yyyy format. for ex- JUN 2013 and MAY 2015. i need the list or array of years between the two dates. For the above dates : 2013,2014,2015. How to achieve this in javascript or JQuery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? A simple loop should do it.

Comment: Just loop between parseInt(X.substr(4,4), 10)

Comment: You could just create date-objects for start-data and end-date and then loop and create and array from them. What have you tried?

Comment: Your examples don't match the specified `MMM-yyyy` format (they don't have a hyphen). You need to at least get the requirement clear in your own mind before you ask for help.

Comment: Dear Bergi, if its a simple loop could you please show it and then down vote???

Comment: did u tried my answer

Comment: @Akram: I've never been asked by an OP to downvote his question, but here you are :-)

Comment: Am trying  Codesen.. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this..

```
    var d = new Date( "01 " + "July 2013");
    first = d.getFullYear();

    var s = new Date( "01 " + "May 2018");
    second = s.getFullYear();
    arr = Array();

   for(i = first; i <= second; i++) arr.push(i);


   alert(arr);
```

Comment: I want the array of the years between them. for your above ex output should be something like 2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018.

Comment: @Akram - That's what this answer does. `arr` will be `[2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var startDate = "JUN 2013",
    endDate = "MAY 2015";

var result = [];
for (var from=+startDate.slice(4),to=+endDate.slice(4); from<=to; from++)
    result.push(from);

console.log(result); // Array [2013, 2014, 2015]
```

Comment: Would have done it in just 3 variables :-) +1 anyhow

Comment: +1, even though there's not enough jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date1 = "JUN 2013";
var date2 = "MAY 2015";
// get the year parts, and convert from strings to numbers:
var year1 = Number(date1.substr(4));
var year2 = Number(date2.substr(4));
// create an empty array:
var yearList = [];
// loop between the two years:
for (var i = year1; i <= year2; i++) {
    // add to array:
    yearList.push(i);
}
// print list of years to the console:
console.log(yearList);
```

If you know your input values will always be in the `MMM yyyy` format there's no need to convert to actual `Date` objects, you can just use the [`String` method `.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to extract the part you need. But it will return it as a *string,* so to do maths operations on it you need to convert it to a number - one way to do that is with [the `Number()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: Too much effort for such a question :-) +1 anyhow

Answer (score 0):

The moment library is quite good at working with dates if you can afford that in your project.

See:
 http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

For returning the number of years difference between two dates and then you can just increment against your starting year and push the new number to an array?

Comment: What do you need the difference for? You can just start incrementing the year…

Answer (score 0):

```
var getArrayOfYears = function(date1 /* MMM YYYY */, date2 /* MMM YYYY */) {

    var arrayOfYears = [];

    // Get the years
    date1 = parseInt(date1.substring(4), 10);
    date2 = parseInt(date2.substring(4), 10);

    // Order the years
    if (date2 > date1) {
        var tmp = date2;
        date2 = date1;
        date1 = tmp;
    }

    // Loop them
    var dif = date1 - date2;
    for (var i = 0; i <= dif; i++) {
        arrayOfYears[arrayOfYears.length] = date1 - i;
    }

    return arrayOfYears;

};
```